# Communicating between siblings in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a CPU emulator in Typescript/React. I've got a `CodeExecutionView`, `CPU` and `Terminal`.

Now, when the `CPU` fires an appropiate instruction, I want to write some data to the `Terminal`. The data I want to write resides in the `CPUstate`. The function I use to write data to the Terminal is in the `TerminalView` component. How can I pass that function for the `CPU` class to use?

Here's how the structure of my code looks like:

```
                   ___________
                  |           |
                  | MAIN VIEW |
                  |(component)|
                  |___________|
          ___________      ___________
         |           |    |           |
         |    CPU    |    | TERMINAL  |
         |  (class)  |    |(component)|
         |___________|    |___________|
```

Main component:

```
type ExecutionState = {
    assemblerOutput: Array<{ line: ParsedLine; bytes: Array<HexNum> }>;
    currentInstruction: Instruction;
    currentPC: number;
    currentInstructionLength: number;
    cpuState: CPUState;
}

type ExecutionProps = {
    assemblerOutput: Array<{ line: ParsedLine; bytes: Array<HexNum> }>;
}

export default class ExecutionScreen extends React.Component<ExecutionProps, ExecutionState> {
    state: ExecutionState = {
        assemblerOutput: [],
        currentInstruction: undefined,
        currentPC: 0,
        currentInstructionLength: 0,
        cpuState: undefined
    }

    private CPU: CPU;

    constructor(props: ExecutionProps) {
        super(props);
        this.CPU = new CPU(props.assemblerOutput);
        this.state = {
            assemblerOutput: props.assemblerOutput,
            currentInstruction: this.CPU.currentInstruction,
            currentPC: this.CPU.prevPC,
            currentInstructionLength: undefined,
            cpuState: this.CPU.getFullState()
        };
    }

    runNextInstruction(): void {
        this.CPU.executeInstruction();
        this.setState({ ...this.state, currentInstruction: this.CPU.currentInstruction, currentInstructionLength: this.CPU.currentInstruction.size, currentPC: this.CPU.prevPC, cpuState: this.CPU.getFullState() });
    }

    render(): ReactElement {
        return (
            <>
                <Button key={0} onClick={ this.runNextInstruction.bind(this) }>Next</Button>
                <TerminalView />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Terminal component:

```
export default class TerminalView extends React.Component {
    private readonly terminalRef: React.RefObject<XTerm>;
    private terminal: Terminal;

    constructor(props: ReactPropTypes) {
        super(props);
        this.terminalRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        this.terminal = this.terminalRef.current.getTerminal();
        this.handleTerminal();
        this.writeHexNum([new HexNum(66), new HexNum(10), new HexNum(66)]);
    }

    render(): React.ReactElement {
        return (
            <>
                <XTerm
                    ref={this.terminalRef}
                />
            </>
        );
    }

    // the function i want to be accesible to the CPU
    // the most important one would be terminal.write()
    writeHexNum(values: Array<HexNum>): void {
        this.terminal.write(values.map(value => value.toAscii()).join(""));
    }
}
```

I would prefer not to change the sctructure of the code because i need the CPU class to exist in the main view for other things to work correctly

Comment: to props of TerminalView add your CP class and to constructor of CP add TerminalView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siblings in react don't communicate directly, instead they need to communicate via a shared parent, which holds the shared state.  You could define an array in the main view state to hold the terminals lines.  Then the CPU can push to that array.  in the code below i have named this variable `terminalLines`.

```
type ExecutionState = {
    assemblerOutput: Array<{ line: ParsedLine; bytes: Array<HexNum> }>;
    currentInstruction: Instruction;
    currentPC: number;
    currentInstructionLength: number;
    cpuState: CPUState;
    terminalLines: string[]
}
```

Then add a property to the terminal and bind it to the array.

```
    render(): ReactElement {
        return (
            <>
                <Button key={0} onClick={ this.runNextInstruction.bind(this) }>Next</Button>
                <TerminalView lines={ this.terminalLines } />
            </>
        );
    }
```

You will need to define a class for the props on the terminal then modify the render to be similar to.

```
    render(props: Props): React.ReactElement {
        this.terminal.write(props.lines.map(value => value.toAscii()).join(""));
        return (
            <>
                <XTerm
                    ref={this.terminalRef}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
```

I have not had a chance to test this code.  You may need to add logic to keep the array growing too large, for example keeping the last few hundred lines.

Comment: This is indeed a good approach. I ultimately decided to make the CPU the main component, but I can confirm that this aproach works